# Create an array in JavaScript such that any change in the array is immediately reflected in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am basically designing a Shopping Cart using JavaScript, specifically jQuery.

Till now, I updated the whole `<div>` that corresponded to the cart every time there is some change (at the server side using some AJAX calls) in the cart array.

Can I simplify this any further so that any change in the 'cart' array is reflected in the DOM immediately with out having to refresh the entire `<div>`?

I would also like to point out that the cart `<div>` is always visible.

I am a beginner. Please help out.

Comment: There's no trivial solution here, no -- other than using something like KnockoutJS, ReactJS, RivetsJS, etc. which has already done the hard work for you.

Comment: Just to add, if you really don't want to go with something like those, take a look at `data binding`. That's the term you're looking for. But you really should use an existing solution. It'll make your life easier.